Flutter run time error : Purging debug resources in release build
I am run flutter old project with flutter SDK : 2.5.0 ,
there is no any error (syntax error), but when i was run i got Error
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[flutter_background_geolocation] Purging debug resources in release build
[flutter_background_geolocation] Purging debug resources in release build
[flutter_background_geolocation] Purging debug resources in release build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/mac/Development/src/flutter/bin/flutter''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.5.0 at /Users/mac/Development/src/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4cc385b4b8 (2 years, 10 months ago), 2021-09-07 23:01:49 -0700
    • Engine revision f0826da7ef
    • Dart version 2.14.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 22.0.2+9-70)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 15.4, Build version 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 22.0.2+9-70)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 126.0.6478.183
    ! Error: Manish’s iPhone Mini is not connected. Xcode will continue when Manish’s iPhone Mini is connected and unlocked. (code -13)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for VPN iPhone 11. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area
      network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)

• No issues found!


pubspec.yaml
name: gor
description: The Flutter client for the Gestolen Objecten Register website.
version: 1.5.5

publish_to: "none"

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.9.3 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=2.2.1"

dependencies:
  animations: 2.0.2
  bloc: ^6.1.3
  cached_network_image: 2.5.1
  camera: 0.9.4+5
  crimson:
    path: packages/crimson
  detection_service:
    path: packages/detection_service
  device_info: 2.0.3
  equatable: 2.0.3
  firebase_core: 1.11.0
  firebase_messaging: 11.2.5
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_background_geolocation: 4.3.2
  flutter_bloc: 6.1.3
  flutter_image_compress: 1.1.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: 0.19.3
  flutter_vector_icons: 1.0.0
  formz: 0.4.1
  geolocator: 8.0.3
  google_maps_flutter: 2.1.1
  google_maps_place_picker:
    path: packages/google_maps_place_picker
  http: 0.13.4
  image_picker: 0.8.4+4
  intl: 0.17.0
  localstorage: 4.0.0+1
  meta: 1.7.0
  multi_image_picker: 4.8.01
  notifications_repository:
    path: packages/notifications_repository
  package_info: 2.0.2
  path: 1.8.0
  path_provider: 2.0.8
  permission_handler: 8.3.0
  photo_view: 0.13.0
  pull_to_refresh: 2.0.0
  rxdart: 0.25.0
  selectable_autolink_text: 2.3.0
  smooth_page_indicator: 1.0.0+2
  sticky_headers: 0.2.0
  stolen_objects_repository:
    path: packages/stolen_objects_repository
  url_launcher: 6.0.18
  very_good_analysis: 2.3.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  intl_translation: 0.17.10+1

dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.17.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/png/
    - assets/images/svg/



also in this project some packages are also used which are located in packages in lib/packages directory

also there was three main.dart file like
main_dev.dart
main_mock.dart
main_prod.dart
